# In TeamCity Professional 7.1.4 (build 24331), how can I specify the build agent's checkout directory?

Tags: teamcity-7.0

Recently we had a server crash and we had to reinstall teamcity. Unfortunately the backup was not done correctly and we have to reconfigure it. We're using the new version, 7.1.4.

In 6.5, I recall being able to specify the checkout directory of the build agent. I'm having a lot of trouble finding the place where I can do that in 7.1.4. But it appears that by default it is:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7af1ebc62605b268
```

I assume that the alphanumeric directory is subject to change.

Perhaps that feature, the option to specify the svn checkout directory, was taken away. In any case, I would like to specify the checkout directory because some of our tests had that parameter hard coded in and it would save me the trouble of determining the run time checkout directory in the code.

The trouble is when I use the MSBUILD option the current directory is actually

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\SYSTEM_DEVSERVER 2013-03-06 22_22_14\Out
```

and one needs to know the teamcity checkout to load the test input files.

Does anyone know if it is indeed possible now, in 7.1.4, to specify the build agent svn checkout directory? If not, I'd better find a workaround.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm blind.

The Checkout directory is in the "Version control settings" configuration step of the build configuration.

By default, it is set to 'Auto'. The textbox to edit it doesn't appear until you select custom path in the combobox above. I must have scanned for the textbox while neglecting to read the combobox titles.

Whoops.